# Is there any way to get body tracking value/coordinate in ARKIT 3?

Tags: ios, xcode, arkit, ios13, xcode11

I want to use ARKIT3 for body tracking and get the value/coordinate. I've checked the sample code from Apple Documentation for capturing body motion in 3D https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/capturing_body_motion_in_3d

I tried to read and understand the code. Read the function on the Apple documentation website but still i don't have any idea how to get the body motion value or coordinate. Is there any way i could get the body motion value and play with it ?